# Mailing a foreach construct

Tags: php, email

I am new to php, so don't hate me if I speak things that don't make sense. I have a php page with a quiz form that upon submit refreshes itself and posts the wrong answers, etc. Now I want to add the functionality to send this result to my email. I managed to get it to send the mail, but I can't get the whole data. This is what checks and prints the questions and answers and (tries to) mails it:

```
if (isset($_POST['answers'])){
    $Answers = $_POST['answers']; 
    foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){              
        if ($Answers[$QuestionNo] != $Value['CorrectAnswer']){  
            echo $Value['Question'].'<br />';
            echo 'Your answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'<br />';
            echo 'Correct answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']];
        } 
        else {}        
    }
    $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $mailTo = 'intrelis@gmail.com';
    $mailFrom = 'From: <mail@mail.com>'; 
    $msgSubject = 'English level test from' . $email;
    $msgBody = ;

    mail ($mailTo, $msgSubject, $msgBody, $xHeaders);    
}
```

I want the same information that is printed on the page sent to my mail, but I don't know how to. What do I put in $msgBody? I tried different ideas, but the body of the mail is always empty...

Comment: Put the same things you `echo` into the message body.

Comment: @Barmar: How should I do that? You mean the whole foreach {*}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation to add each question and answer to the message body in the loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['answers'])){
    $msgBody = '';
    $Answers = $_POST['answers']; 
    foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value){              
        if ($Answers[$QuestionNo] != $Value['CorrectAnswer']){  
            echo $Value['Question'].'<br />';
            echo 'Your answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'<br />';
            echo 'Correct answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']];
            $msgBody .= "Question: {$Value['Question']}\nHis answer: {$Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]]}\nCorrect answer: {$Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']]}\n\n";
        } 
        else {}        
    }
    $email = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $mailTo = 'intrelis@gmail.com';
    $mailFrom = 'From: <mail@mail.com>'; 
    $msgSubject = 'English level test from' . $email;

    mail ($mailTo, $msgSubject, $msgBody, $xHeaders);    
}
```

Comment: Seems so logical now that I look at it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should store answer in var like this

```
//Define variable on top outside loop
$your_answer = '';
$correct_answer = '';

...
$your_answer .= 'Your answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]];

$correct_answer .= 'Correct answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']];

...
//After loop
echo $your_answer.'<br />';
echo $correct_answer;
```

and in mail concate it in body

```
$msgBody = $your_answer . "\n" . $correct_answer ."\n";
```

Comment: That will only mail the last answer. You need to append to the message body each time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I totally overlooked that i am in loop

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see where you assign the variable '$msgBody'. Here is an example how this can be done:

```
<?php

function sendMail($msgBody)
{

$email = $_POST['userEmail'];
$mailTo = 'intrelis@gmail.com';
$mailFrom = 'From: <mail@mail.com>';
$msgSubject = 'English level test from' . $email;

mail($mailTo, $msgSubject, $msgBody, $xHeaders);

}

if (isset($_POST['answers'])) {
$Answers = $_POST['answers'];
$output = "";
foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value) {
    if ($Answers[$QuestionNo] != $Value['CorrectAnswer']) {

        $newOutput = $Value['Question'] . '<br />';
        $newOutput .= 'Your answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]] . '<br />';
        $newOutput .= 'Correct answer: ' . $Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']];

        echo $newOutput;
        $output .= $newOutput;

    } else {
    }
}
sendMail($output);
}
```